# How to fix the issue regarding docker-compose can't open file?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am not able to find a solution to an issue with docker-compose, the issue basically is that when the container is launched from docker-compose it says that a file is not found, please see the details below:

**command**:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache --force-rm --pull && docker-compose up --force-recreate --always-recreate-deps --build --renew-anon-volumes --remove-orphans
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: './dockerFolder'
    volumes:
      - /home/user/my_user:/app
```

**Dockerfile**

```sh
FROM python:3

# Cloning repository
RUN git clone MY_REPOSITORY_URL /app

# Installing project requirements
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Run app on container creation
CMD [ "python", "src/app.py" ]
```

**Error**

```
python: can't open file '/app/src/app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: does it work when you use `docker build` instead of docker-compose?

Comment: You volume map onto `/app` hiding everything in the image in `/app` and directories below it. So for it to work, you need to have a `/home/user/my_user/src/app.py` file on the host. Do you have that?

Comment: Volumes are added and accessible after image is build (it's not in the process of building), so either you should add `COPY requirements.txt .` or `COPY . .` after `WORKDIR /app` and see if it works.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `volumes:` block that @HansKilian identified in order to run the image.  Is deleting it an option?  (Do you actually have a copy of the source tree locally?  There are a couple of practical problems running `git clone` inside a Dockerfile.)

Comment: yes it work when I use docker build instead of docker compose

Comment: as the build with docker-compose is not successfully, the volume is empty

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks a lot, I realize that the volume declaration in the docker-compose.yml file was the issue, as you said it hide all the content on container creation thus the files were not accessible by the CMD or ENTRYPOINT. I just delete that and it works like a charm.